# Using the epsilon-delta definition, prove that the $\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} \frac{2x}{x-3}=-4$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Here is what I have so far, and I am new to these kinds of proofs so please be detailed with me:
$| \frac{2x}{x-3}-(-4) | = |\frac{6(x-2)}{x-3}|$

But I don't understand what I am supposed to do with this! I just don't understand. I know the answer, but I have no idea how to get there. The answer is:

$ \delta = min{(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{12}})$

Comment: Are you allowed to state that the function is rational, and the limit is taken at a point where the denominator is nonzero, so it is continuous, and $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)$?

Comment: I don't think so? It may be true, but we haven't really talked about continuous functions yet.

Comment: Also, why are you taking the infimum of a two element set? Just take the minimum.

Comment: You're right! Oops, I will edit that.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the sum/difference and product of limits?

Comment: Yes! What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such a case it is often quite useful to use a substitution like

- $\boxed{x-2 = h} $ and check what happens to the expression as $\boxed{h \rightarrow 0}$
- and note that $\boxed{|x-2| < \delta \Leftrightarrow |h| < \delta}$

$$| \frac{2x}{x-3}-(-4) | = |\frac{6(x-2)}{x-3}|$$ 
$$ \stackrel{x-2 = h}{=} 6\frac{|h|}{|h-1|}$$ 
$$ \stackrel{ |h-1|=|1-h| \geq |1-|h||}{\leq} 6\frac{|h|}{|1-|h||}$$
$$ \color{blue}{\stackrel{ |h| < \frac{1}{2}}{<} 12}|h|$$
It follows immediately
$$\epsilon > 0 \Rightarrow \delta = \min \left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}},\frac{\epsilon}{\color{blue}{12}}\right)$$

Indeed, for $\delta = \min \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{12}\right) \Leftrightarrow |h| < \min \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{\epsilon}{12}\right)$ you get
$$\color{blue}{| \frac{2x}{x-3}-(-4) | <} 12|h| \leq 12\frac{\epsilon}{12} = \color{blue}{\epsilon}$$

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't exactly a direct $\epsilon{-}\delta$ proof, but it is quick. The Algebraic Limit Theorem for functions says that, if $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=a$ and $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=b$, then $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)/g(x)=a/b$ (assuming $b\neq0$). So
$$ \lim_{x\to2}\frac{2x}{x-3}=\frac{\lim_{x\to2} 2x}{\lim_{x\to2} x-3}=\frac4{-1}=-4. $$

Comment: This is a great answer, actually. I don't know if I'd be able to use it on the exam given the specific question, but I think it's a good answer regardless.

Comment: Glad it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume $|\frac{6(x-2)}{x-3}|$ < positive $\epsilon$ and find a $\delta$ > 0 so that
for all x, if |x - 2| < $\delta,$ then $|\frac{6(x-2)}{x-3}| < \epsilon.$

A delta smaller than what the answer gives is acceptable.